# select every checkbox on an entire page

Tags: javascript, html

assuming the following code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="categories[9507]">
```

is there a javascript command that can simply select every checkbox like that on the page? the name's change slightly in numbers only.

I need to select around 15000 on a page, without a select all available :(

(something that I could put into a bookmark and click, or console of firebug would be best)

Comment: What do you mean by select? Add focus to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pure JS, modern browsers-only (IE 8+, FF 3.5+, Opera 10+, Safari 3.2+, Chrome 1+):

```
(function() {
    var chs = document.querySelectorAll​('input[type="checkbox"][name^="categories"]')​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​;
    for (var i=0; i<chs.length; i++) chs[i].checked = true;
}());
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/sUGTQ/)

[QSA Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll)

Comment: No check for `querySelectorAll` compatibility?

Comment: @EthanB I stated "Modern browsers". OP is going to put it in a bookmarklet, I do hope he is not using IE<8 as his main browser.

Comment: It's for "bookmark or firebug console". Sounds like a productivity thing for OP, so doesn't matter.

Comment: Exactly as @Hamish stated, I'd put an working answer for IE<8 but that'd be just wasting my time to write it, your time to read it, OP's time and SO's db space. Also, RobG already put an working version since IE4. `=]`

Answer (score 2):

In plain script for any browser since IE 4:

```
function checkAllCheckboxes(root) {
  root = root || document;
  var inputs = root.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for (var i=0, iLen=inputs.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].type == 'checkbox') inputs[i].checked = true;
  }
}
```

*root* can be any element containing the checkboxes in question or nothing for the entire document. A regular expression test can be added to check only those whose name starts with "categories", e.g.

```
  var re = /^categories/;
  var input;
    ...
      input = inputs[i];
    if (input.type == 'checkbox' && re.test(input.name)) {
      input.checked = true;
    }
  ...
```

As a one line bookmark:

```
javascript:var e,es=document.getElementsByTagName('input'),i=0,iL=es.length,r=/^categories/;for(;i<iL;){e=es[i++];if(e.type=="checkbox"&&r.test(e.name))e.checked=true}void 0;
```

#### Edit

Made bookmark shorter. A few more characters can be removed if required.

Comment: should check the name attribute too.

Comment: It does now. :-) Requirements are ambiguous, subject is "every…entire", but body seems to add the name requirement. Over to the OP…

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked','checked');​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: Don't assume jQuery. And if you do, SAY so.

Comment: Did you downvote Fabricio's too? NRGdallas wanted something that he could put in a bookmarklet or console and you can't do that with his answer.

Comment: yes you can. Also, Fab was the only one to handle the name attribute.

Comment: I tried it in the latest version of GC and it wouldn't accept it as a bookmark or in the console.

Comment: If you have a problem with another solution, comment on it.

Comment: Just wondering why you're quick to judge but not supply you're own answer

Comment: A downvote isn't a personal attack. SO is about good quality answers, and I've explained the problems. Spend your energy improving your answer, instead of complaining about it. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/112664/154753

Answer (score -1):

Use http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/

```
jQuery(':checkbox').click();
```

Comment: I didn't downvote... I'm wondering who downvoted mine (without explanation).

Comment: I didn't downvote any answer here, but honestly, 1. No need for jQuery; 2. Triggering a `click` event unnecessarily when you only need to set a property, I'd downvote this if it didn't work.

Comment: -1 The OP was how to select (i.e. check) every checkbox. You need to set the checked property to true.

Comment: Prob because you assume jquery

Comment: I downvoted it, for the reasons stated by @FabrícioMatté. OP didn't tag jQuery, and clearly no need to load an huge external library for somethign so simple.

Comment: Also, no mention of the checkbox name attr.

Comment: I would recommend not to assume and target the least possible version of the browsers on the client desktop and code accordingly. Eg:- WinXP its IE7. (IE6 is almost dead) Would just make a button and then on click event check all the check boxes as desired. Search on google for some references. You are bound to find.